# Show heads of one branch?

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to ask Mercurial to show only the heads of one branch? For example, I often want to double-check that `default` only has one head, but currently I need to do that "manually" (ie, checking the output of `hg heads` for more than one entry which is in `default`).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`hg heads <branch name>` works on Mercurial 1.5.3.

Answer (score 6):

To get the heads of the current branch you can use:

```
hg heads .
```

And to get the *number* of heads of the current branch (in Bash):

```
hg heads -q . | wc -l
```